# Download latest snapshot artifact from Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.30.0-01using wget/curl command

Tags: awk, wget, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I am facing difficulty downloading the latest  snapshot version from Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.30.0-01 using wget /curl

the problem I am  facing is that  in nexus there are multiple version of artefacts  within the same snapshot version appended with timestamp plus - an incremental number like the below  image

[image]

[image]
[image]

so how to download the latest snapshot version from multiple version under one snapshot?

currently, I have to specify explicitly specify the version like the below one

wget http://$NEXUS_URL/repository/mfi-snapshots/com/mf/productService/1.0.9-SNAPSHOT/**productService-1.0.9-20210329.141405-11.war**

So is there any way to download the latest version  with just mentioning the snapshot version and download the latest ver

```
 $NEXUS_URL: is the nexus URL 
mfi-snapshots: is the snapshot repo
com.mf: is the group 
productService is the artefact
1.0.9 SNAPSHOT the version of the artefact
```

I tried to use "/v1/search/assets/download" API defined in nexus ( not sure how to use it

http://$NEXUS_URL/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&direction=desc&q=war&repository=mfi-snapshots&group=com.mf&name=productService

which given a json output like
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465488-How-can-I-retrieve-a-snapshot-if-I-don-t-know-the-exact-filename-) help?

Comment: No, look for nexus3 it won't work, or I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps mentioned in help article on sonatype and I got the solution

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset

```
curl -L -o productService.war  -s -X GET "$NEXUS_HOST/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=$NEXUS_SNAPSHOTS_REPO&maven.groupId=com.mf&maven.artifactId=productService&maven.baseVersion=$SNAPSHOT_VERSION&maven.extension=war" -H "accept: application/json"
```